# textarea to accept 12 comma separated values for input type text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want my input tag to accept only maximum 12 comma separated values.it should not accept values like  `1,` mean after comma their is nothing this is the regex I have made.

My current regex is not accepting single value like `1 or a or 12ab`

```
^[0-9a-zA-z]+(,[0-9a-zA-z]+){1,11}$
```

checked it on http://www.phpliveregex.com/ but it is not working. Here is my whole code

```
if(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-z]+(,[0-9a-zA-z]+){1,11}$/", $data){
        return false
}else{
        return $data
}
```

Comment: I see that your second `z` in the RegEx is a lower-case one. You want to make it an upper-case `Z` in order to match the correct range. Which means the character groups should look like this: `[0-9a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Thanks ChristianF let me test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(,[0-9a-zA-Z]+){0,11}$
                             ^^
```

This should do it for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nN4oT8/4

Comment: @UsamaLucky To explain why this works: You asked for a value, followed by at minimum one more value seperated by a comma. You wanted it to be followed by a minimum of 0 more values. ;)

Comment: Thanks vks and ChristianF let me test it